# Can Javascript/jQuery auto-populate a readonly text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, readonly

I have an area of my application that requires the user to agree to a statement, and I am using Javascript/jQuery so that when the user selects 'Yes' it automatically enters the date/time into a readonly field.

Although I cannot reproduce it, I am having multiple users tell me that when they select 'Yes', it does not populate the date/time and since the field is readonly they cannot type it in themselves.

Is there anything in my code that is unconventional that would cause the issues described above in particular browsers?  Can anyone reproduce this on their machines?

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YL2Wd/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>I agree:*</label>
    <span class="options">
        <label for="agreement_no">No</label>
        <input type="radio" class="required authorization" value="0" id="agreement_no" name="agreement">

        <label for="agreement_yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" class="required authorization" value="1" id="agreement_yes" name="agreement">
    </span>
</div>
<div class="description">
    Agreement Text
</div>
<div class="question">
    <label for="authorization_timestamp">Date/Time*</label>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" maxlength="100" class="authorization_timestamp required" name="authorization_timestamp" id="authorization_timestamp">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.authorization[id$="yes"]').on('change', function() {

    var dateStr;

    if ($(this).val() == 1) {

        var now = new Date();

        var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = now.getDate();
        var year = now.getFullYear();
        var h = now.getHours();
        var m = now.getMinutes();
        var s = now.getSeconds();

        month = month < 10 ? "0" + month : month;
        day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day;
        h = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h;
        m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
        s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;

        dateStr = month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s
    }

    $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().find(".authorization_timestamp").first().val(dateStr);

});

$('.authorization[id$="no"]').on('change', function() {

    var dateStr;
    dateStr = "";
    $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().find(".authorization_timestamp").first().val(dateStr);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().find(".authorization_timestamp").first().val(dateStr);
```

just use

```
 $("#authorization_timestamp").val(dateStr);
```

That means you should go for `id` or `class` to point that element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/UCTEv/)**

---

> #### Try to avoid .next().next()... chaining. because it's brittle and  will cause break of html. Alway try to use `id` or `class` to point the element. Some browser cause issue with that and create empty text node around there.

---

***If you are not interested to change your code at all (not good, you should) then***

```
    $(this)
        .parent()   // go to span
        .parent()  // jump to parent div
        .next()   // .description div
        .next('.question') // .question div
        .find('.authorization_timestamp')  // find the input
        .val(dateStr); // set value
```

And a little edit for your query:

```
  $(this)
        .parent()
        .parent()
        .nextAll('.question')
        .find(".authorization_timestamp")
        .val(dateStr);
```

#### According to your comment:

try like this:

```
var index = this.id                          // get id of radio
                  .replace('agreement','')   // replace agreement string
                  .replace('_yes','');       // replace yes string
                                             // output: 1, 2, 3 ...

$("input#authorization" + index + '_timestamp')   // get the target input field 
                                                  // using that index, because your
                                                  // html is synchronous with index
                                    .val(dateStr);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/YL2Wd/7/)**

I do it for `yes`, similarly do it for `no`.

Comment: Never use a selector like that `parent().parent().next()` it's way too brittle and will break with most changes to the HTML. You should always look for a class or an id

Comment: @JuanMendes I know that and my first suggestion is for that, but I will add your suggestion to my answer, thanks sir

Comment: The reason I was doing chaining was because my forms/questions are dynamically created, and there may be multiple authorization agreements, one after each other.  See http://jsfiddle.net/YL2Wd/4/ What is the best way to select the correct text field in this case?

Comment: @thecodeparadox Thanks so much for your help!  However, the timestamp fields do not necessarily follow a pattern of authorization1_timestamp, authorization2_timestamp, authorization3_timestamp.  I was just using this for the example.  They might be have totally different names.  The only consistencies throughout are the class "authorization" for the radio buttons and the class "authorization_timestamp" for the text fields. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Michael if timestamp field are not fixed, then which part of you html is fixed suppose `.question` is fixed

Comment: The class "authorization" for the radio buttons and the class "authorization_timestamp" for the text fields.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YL2Wd/12/) to demonstrate an easy way to do this.  Basically, when you dynamically create the radio button inputs, add an attribute `data-timestamp` that points to the dynamically-generated ID of the associated timestamp textbox, as such:

```
<input type="radio" class="required authorization" value="0" id="agreement1_no" data-timestamp="authorization1_timestamp" name="agreement1">
<input type="radio" class="required authorization" value="1" id="agreement1_yes" data-timestamp="authorization1_timestamp" name="agreement1">
```

Then, in your jQuery function, grab the value of that attribute and use it as a jQuery selector to set the value of the textbox.

```
var targetElement = "#" + $(this).attr("data-timestamp");
$(targetElement).val(dateStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

thecodeparadox already showed you what to do `$("#authorization_timestamp").val(dateStr);`. The reason it may not work in some browsers may be because of how empty text nodes are created around HTML elements.

If you change your HTML not to contain any spaces, your selector should work. Having said that, using code like

```
$(this).parent().parent().nextAll()
```

Is a sure way to break your code with any minor changes to the HTML.

**Making it work without using IDs**
If there may be multiple `authorization_timestamp`s, you cannot assign an id. Make it a class and use something like the following

```
<!-- Add a div with a class around all your HTML so you can properly 
     walk up and back down to the search field to your form wrapper -->
<div class="form-wrapper">old content</div>...
```

Now find your element like the following

```
$(this).parents(".form-wrapper").find("authorization_timestamp");
```

I created a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/YL2Wd/11/ I also improved your code so it doesn't need two separate handlers.

Comment: The reason I was doing chaining was because my forms/questions are dynamically created, and there may be multiple authorization agreements, one after each other.  See http://jsfiddle.net/YL2Wd/4/ What is the best way to select the correct text field in this case?

Comment: @Michael See my update to the answer, it contains a working jsfiddle

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for multiple agreements.  See http://jsfiddle.net/YL2Wd/13/

Comment: @Michael You didn't understand the code... You have to put `<div class='form-wrapper'></div>` around each set of fields. http://jsfiddle.net/YL2Wd/14/ The script crawls up to the `form-wrapper` then down into the text field

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure I will be able to change the HTML to add an additional wrapper in at this point, but I'll see.  I think since these forms are already created, they might have to stay in their current format for now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you can't control the HTML, you are stuck with brittle searches and broken code as the HTML updates. How hard can it be to modify the HTML?